# Missing DatetimeIndex after reading h5 with R

Tags: r, rhdf5

I have an .h5 file that when opened with pandas in python looks like this:

```
my_file.info()
```

- < class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' >
- DatetimeIndex: 3641767 entries,
  2016-02-27 10:23:52 to 2016-03-18 17:39:52
- Data columns (total 10 columns):

ecc...

Now, I tried to import it in R, using *rhdf5* package and the *DatetimeIndex* does not seem to be there - for instance using *h5ls* command,  to visualize the structure.

Could you help me to find it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't know how... In python I can access it simply with `my_file.index`... - so, maybe this could help you to understand how the datetimeindex is represented in python and you could figure out how I could access it in R too... - hope this help...